# Connect to DB on cloud via SSL?

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, laravel-4, laravel-5.1

In the `.env` file, how would I set the database configuration to read from cloud db via SSL, provided with SSL certificate files?

Here is what clearDB says at configuration of PHP:

```
# In order to connect via SSL using PHP, you'll need to use the "MySQLi" extension,
# like this:

$db = mysqli_init();
$db->ssl_set(PATH_TO_SSL_CLIENT_KEY_FILE, PATH_TO_SSL_CLIENT_CERT_FILE, PATH_TO_CA_CERT_FILE, null, null);
$db->real_connect(HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE_NAME);
```

But is this possible to configure in Laravel `.env` file?

Comment: Do you have those certs already?

Comment: Yes, I can get them.

Comment: [found on laravel.io](http://laravel.io/forum/06-18-2014-connecting-mysql-over-ssl?page=1) - btw, you could add new parameter to `.env` files and retrieve it with `env('key','default_value')` function - just look around at the `config/database.php` i'm sure you'll figure it out.